# Parse HTML Email Verification Mail Template

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a possibility to set HTML body to the password recovery and the email verification mail?
As I can see, the template which can be modified in parse.com is a plain text body.

If there is no option for this from the settings menu, can we somehow catch the signup request (Parse user.signUp), and send out manually the emails? The other problem here would be to generate the links..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Facing the same issue. I searched around and the only thing I found is to use an additional service: Maybe using Parse Cloud Code with the Module 'Mandrill' (it's an email service by MailChimp) could solve this. Here's a lead: parse.com/questions/sending-email-with-mandrill-on-ios